# Log some summary data to the execution results window

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I'm reasonably new to pentaho spoon and I'm trying to find a way to write the result of a query to the execution results window.

I'm importing a lot of data into a number of postgres tables and I'd like to log the number of rows that the tables hold at the end on my job.

I can run the following query in postgres to get the information I want:

```
select relname as table_name, n_live_tup as rows
from pg_stat_user_tables
where pg_stat_user_tables.n_live_tup > 0
order by relname asc;
```

But I can't figure out get the dozen rows returned into the log window.

Comment: Is there a reason the `Write to Log` step won't work for you?

Comment: @eicherjc the Write to Log step doesn't allow me to have a query (or table input) as an input to it. It just allows me to write something like 'hello world'

Comment: Use `Write to Log` in a transformation, not a job, and it will log out the output of Table Input or whatever other step it's connected to.

Comment: Thanks @eicherjc if you submit it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.